# *ngFor keyvalue descOrder doesn't work with date

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm using entities

the format is like

```
{
  'mongooseId': {
    title: 'my title',
    created: '2018-08-31T10:04:52.673Z'
  }
}
```

and I'd like :) to put them

in descOrder by the created field

```
descOrder(a, b){
  if(a.value.created > b.value.created){
    return b.value.created;
  }
}
*ngFor="let post of posts | keyvalue:descOrder"
```

but it doesn't work

even if I cast che string to date

new Date(a.value.created)

### UPDATE

I change the format of the date

using Date.now() so now its a number

and with this code it works :)

```
descOrder(a, b){
    if(b.value.created > a.value.created) {
      return a.value.created;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How about returning `new Date(a.value.created) - new Date(b.value.created)`. Not sure about the API here, but sorting in JS is usually done like that.

Comment: Can you please update the question with `posts` json here in the question?

Answer (score 1):

`return b.key` for that

```
descOrder(a, b){
  if(a.value.created < b.value.created){
    return b.key;
  }
}
```